# Kerberos constrained delegation with protocol transition in java on linux

Tags: kerberos

I am not able to find any examples of how constrained delegation with protocol transition is done using JAAS/GSS api's on linux. Appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: I've summarized all the necessary details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57377671/1471779

Answer (score 1):

I guess, there is only support for credential delegation. You cannot specify the explicit target hosts.

Comment: yep java doesn't have support for credential delegation with protocol transition, had to buy a proprietary library to get that support.

Comment: Which one was it? Out of curiousity.

Comment: I´m also curious on which one you used. Can you please tell which one was it? Thanks.

Comment: Probably [this](http://www.quest.com/single-sign-on-for-java/) product from Quest Software.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but related: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099321/how-to-implement-kerberos-protocol-transition-in-java-s4u2self

Comment: Constrained delegation has been implemented in Java 8: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-8.html